# fullcalendar bootstrap tooltip and modal

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm looking to integrate a calendar to my website.

I want to have a bootstrap tooltip on a hover in a day, and a bootstrap modal on a click on a day.

Anyboy knows how to do this?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 'dayClick' and 'dayRender' callbacks to achieve this.
in 'dayRender' you would attach the $.on('hover')... event to the 'cell' element.